# Woocom Rest API Slug Returning 403 on Correct Slug

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I'm getting the 403 Error on this slug any idea's why?

```
https://TheSite/wp-json/wc/reports?period=week&consumer_key=xxxxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxx
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Missing the Version in the Slug

```
// V2 / v1 /v3 Depending on what you need
https://TheSite/wp-json/wc/v3/reports?period=week&consumer_key=xxxxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxx
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that Thank you!, I will try it and get back to you